# Powershell - select data from single CSV cell

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to take the 2nd value from a cell along an entire column which is a Samaccountname, each cell has many values separated by ";", the column has no title or header.

then I need to export to a new csv, those samaccountname values plus the property "Account expires" of each one in the next column.

can you help me?

CSV FORMAT

---

AAA;BBB;CCC;DDD

---

AAA2;BBB2;CCC2;DDD2

---

and so on... it´s just the first column I need to extract info from, about other columns I don´t care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently your CSV looks like this:

```
AccountExpires;SamAccountname;Displayname;Company;Manager
date1;user1;name1;Co1;Boss1
date2;user2;name2;Co2;Boss2
```

Then:

```
# just take the SamAccountname column values and ignore the rest
(Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Original.csv' -Delimiter ';').SamAccountname | ForEach-Object {
    # calculate the account expiration date
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Properties AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        $expires = if ($user.accountExpires -gt 0 -and $user.accountExpires -ne 9223372036854775807) { $user.AccountExpirationDate }
                   else { 'Never Expires' }
        # output an object
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            SamAccountName = $_
            AccountExpires = $expires
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$_' does not exist"
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\ExpiringAccounts.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output ExpiringAccounts.csv will be something like this when opened in Notepad:

```
"SamAccountName","AccountExpires"
"user1","Never Expires"
"user2","6/5/2021 4:36 PM"
```

Comment: Not really, all those values i just put there (AAA;BBB;CCC;DDD) are in a single cell, the cell below contains same type of information but different values. Of all the cells in the same column i must take the 2nd value, each value is separated by a ";". After i take that value i must script to get the Account expires property of each of those values and write them to a new CSV (just to not overwrite the reading file) with all the samaccount name values in a column, and all the accountexpires values in the next column. I hope i made myself clear this time.

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm not used to CSV files, i'm talking about cells cause the file is opened in excel, but opening in notepad makes it clear that there is no cell
It's listed as below

AccountExpires; SamAccountname; Displayname; Company; Manager
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
date1;user1;name1;Co1;Boss1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
date2;user2;name2;Co2;Boss2
...

BTW: The first column (AccountExpires) has outdated values so i cannot take them to make the new output.

Comment: @Salvador All this you should have been mentioned in the question itself, not in comments because they are hard to read. Anyway, I have now changed my answer for you

Comment: How can this be modified to save the samaccountname and accountexpirationdate as titles for the new file? so it can be used for the next execution, current code search for those values to run.